# Can't read a pdf file on Android downloaded from my back Spring

Tags: android, spring, android-studio, file

I can't read with Acrobat Reader a created file.pdf on my Android Studio (pdf is an exemple, I also need .jpg or .txt) because there is an error.

```
private void uriGetDocumentGedFindById(Integer id, String extension) throws Throwable {

    String url = PreferencesFragment.DEFAULT_SERVER_URL_DOCUMENTGEDFINDBYID + id;
    MyHttpClient client = new MyHttpClient(url);
    URL url2 = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url2.openConnection();
    responsUriGetDocumentGedFindById = client.getResponseHttpURLConnection(urlConnection);

    String name = id.toString() + "." + extension;
    saveFile(responsUriGetDocumentGedFindById, name, PreferencesFragment.DOCUMENTS_FOLDER);
}

public void saveFile(String json, String name, String path) throws IOException {
    try {
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(
                new File(mContext.getFilesDir().toString() + path, name));
        writer.write(json);
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public String getResponseHttpURLConnection(HttpURLConnection urlConnection) {

    StringBuffer response = null;
    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        response = new StringBuffer();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response.toString();
}
```

I receive this from my back : via Postman on the left (this is functional, I can read the pdf), in my file.pdf (on Android Studio) on the right (there is an error with Acrobat Reader)

[image]

So first I can't read my file.pdf and second the file.pdf is bigger than the original whitout any additional information (original 200Ko and my file.pdf 400Ko) this is perhaps a clue...

My back :

```
    @Override
public ResponseEntity<Resource> findByIdDocumentGed(Integer id) throws FileNotFoundException {
    DocumentGed documentGed = documentGedService.findByIdDocumentGed(id);

    InputStreamResource resource = null;
    try {
        Integer idFile = documentGed.getFichierCourant().getId();
        String extensionFile = documentGed.getFichierCourant().getTypeFichier().getExtension();

        File file = new File(nasIris + "/ged/import/" + idFile + "." + extensionFile);
        resource = new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(file));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (resource == null) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(resource, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<>(resource, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use [FileOutputStream](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileOutputStream) instead FileWriter ?

Comment: ```FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(
                    new File(mContext.getFilesDir().toString() + path, name));
            byte[] strToBytes = json.getBytes();
            fileOutputStream.write(strToBytes); ```

Unfortunetely I have the same behaviour with this code. Same double size and same error with Acrobate Reader